# define a variable if its undefined using Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

How to defined a variable in Javascript, if its not defined. I tried:

```
var str = "answer";
if(eval(str) == undefined)
   eval("var " + str + " = {}");
alert(answer);
```

but its displaying error: **ReferenceError: answer is not defined**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have to do it from a name that's in a javascript variable (that isn't known ahead of time), then you can do it like this:

```
var str = "answer";
if (typeof window[str] == "undefined") {
    window[str] = {};
}
```

This uses the fact that all global variables are properties of the window object (in a browser).

---

If you know the name of the variable ahead of time, then you can simply do this:

```
var answer = answer || {};
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (typeof answer == "undefined") var answer = {};`

Eval is executed in separate context.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(someUndefinedVariable === undefined){
    var someUndefinedVariable = 'whatever you want' 
}
alert(someUndefinedVariable) //obviously not undefined anymore
```

### **EDIT:** code below is not working

<s>or if you do not know the variable name at time of writing the code</s>

```
var propertyName = 'answer'; //could be generated during runtime
if(window[propertyName] === undefined){
    var window[propertyName] = 'whatever you want';
}
alert(window[propertyName]);
```

Comment: The first example works. http://jsfiddle.net/kQYTy/

However in the second one I jumped to conclusions.

Comment: The reason the first example works, is because the variable is "hoisted" to the top in their context. http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting  
Just 

    if(someUndefinedVariable === undefined){}

will fail though, since you don't declare it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `typeof` with `===` operator and `'undefined'` (to be sure that nobody overwrote undefined variable) to check if variable is undefined and when it is then assign value to it:

```
if (typeof answer === 'undefined') {
    var answer = 'Foo bar';
}
```

Comment: This will always result in answer being equal to 'Foo bar', even if it was defined before (for example in the closure). Google 'variable hoisting js'